# Django many-to-many return list of releated objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a many to many relationship between model Stuff and model Thing.  When Stuff is converted to a string I would like to return a list of things that make it up.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Stuff(models.Model):
    things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)

    def __str__(self):
        # Return comma delimited list of things that are related to self
```

I've seen a lot of many to many problems that are solved by using `stuff.thing.all()`.  If I use `.get()` on thing how do I filter for Stuff's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '-'.join([str(thing) for thing in self.things.all()])
```

This will print `thing1-thing2-thing3` when the `Stuff` object gets printed (you should define a `__str__` method in your `Thing` model as well, otherwise it will print `Thing object-Thing object-Thing object`).

If you want to filter `Thing` objects by `Stuff` ID, you can do:

```
Thing.objects.filter(stuff__id=yourIDHere)
```

Take a look at the [Django docs on lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Awesome.  I had a TypeError at first and had to make one small adjustment.  `return '-'.join([str(thing.name) for thing in self.things.all()])`

Comment: You're right! I missed that! I'll edit that in the answer in case someone else needs it.